# Trying to get Search results from android browser

Tags: android, browser-history

I am trying to get my search values from the android browser with following code:

```
public void getBrowserHist() {
        String[] mColumnStrings =
                       { Browser.SearchColumns._ID,
                                Browser.SearchColumns.SEARCH,   
                                Browser.SearchColumns.DATE
                       };

                 Cursor mCur = getContentResolver().query(Browser.SEARCHES_URI,
                        mColumnStrings, Browser.SearchColumns.SEARCH, null, null);
        int url = mCur.getColumnIndex(Browser.SearchColumns.SEARCH);
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Bookmarks count: " + mCur.getCount());
        mCur.moveToFirst();

            while (!mCur.isAfterLast()) {
                Log.v("titleIdx", mCur.getString(url));

                mCur.moveToNext();

        }
    }
```

The problem is that search result is empty. the mcur.getCount() method returns 0, and I don´t now why. Does anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cursor cursor = this.context.getContentResolver().query(Browser.SEARCHES_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            final int indexDate = cursor.getColumnIndex(Browser.SearchColumns.DATE);
            final int indexTerm = cursor.getColumnIndex(Browser.SearchColumns.SEARCH);
            String date = cursor.getString(indexDate);
            String term = cursor.getString(indexTerm);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
```